# How can I find when the last shift started? (on 24 hr schedule)

Tags: c#, time

When you have different groups of people working 24 hours a day on different shifts (say one group works three 8-hour shifts, another works two 12-hour shifts, last group works two 10-hour shifts with 4 hours unmanned) given a point in time what is the most straight forward way to return which shift started most recently?

For one example, I have a List of  8 hour `Shift`s (which BeginTime's are 6am, 2pm, 10pm respectively)

```
 public class Shift
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan BeginTime { get; set; }
        public int LengthHours { get; set; }
    }
```

My current code works (for my purposes) but isn't ideal as it requires startTime and that the shifts be in order in the collection.

```
public Shift FindCurrentShift(DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime, List<Shift> shifts)
{
    Shift mostRecentShift = null;
    foreach (Shift aShift in shifts) {
        DateTime shiftBeginTime = DateTime.Parse(endTime.Date.Add(aShift.BeginTime).ToString());
        if (startTime.Date != endTime.Date) {
            if (shiftBeginTime.TimeOfDay > startTime.TimeOfDay) {
                shiftBeginTime = shiftBeginTime.AddDays(-1);
            }
        }
        //does this shift fall in between start and stop time
        if ((startTime < shiftBeginTime && endTime > shiftBeginTime)) {
            mostRecentShift = aShift;
        }
    }
    return mostRecentShift;
}
```

Given the current time, what shift am I in? What is a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure of the SO etiquette if I should have just updated mayabelle's answer but this one has been improved to remove LINQ query duplication and fix a few errors.

```
public Shift FindCurrentShift(DateTime currentDateTime)
{
    Shift shift = LastShift(currentDateTime, currentDateTime.Date);
// not in shift that started today? then check yesterday
    if (shift == null) {
        shift = LastShift(currentDateTime, currentDateTime.Date.AddDays(-1));
    }
    return shift;
}

private Shift LastShift(DateTime currentDateTime, DateTime startOfDay)
{
return shifts.Where(s => startOfDay.Add(s.BeginTime) <= currentDateTime
               && startOfDay.Add(s.BeginTime).AddHours(s.LengthHours) >= currentDateTime)
        .OrderByDescending(s => s.BeginTime)
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
//initalize this with shifts
public List<Shift> shifts;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this by using LINQ:

```
public Shift FindCurrentShift(DateTime currentDateTime, List<Shift> shifts)
{
    DateTime startOfDay = currentDateTime.Date;

    // Get most recent shift that started today and has not ended yet
    Shift shift = 
        shifts.Where(s => startOfDay.Add(s.BeginTime) <= currentDateTime
                     && startOfDay.Add(s.BeginTime).AddHours(s.LengthHours) <= currentDateTime)
              .OrderByDescending(s => s.BeginTime)
              .FirstOrDefault();

    // If none were found that had a start date today, get the latest shift
    // (would be one that started yesterday) as long as its end time today has not passed yet
    if (shift == null) {
        shift =
            shifts.Where(s => startOfDay.AddDays(-1).Add(s.BeginTime).AddHours(s.LengthHours) <= currentDateTime
                  .OrderByDescending(s => s.BeginTime)
                  .FirstOrDefault();
    }

    return shift;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I like it but it gives the wrong shift! 2nd comparison should be `<=`. Essentially you are doing the same LINQ query twice so this could be re-factored to eliminate duplication by separating the LINQ statement into its own method.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using recursion and LINQ could look like this:

```
/// iterate backwards until a shift is found
/// the recursion stops automatically when the last shift is found
/// AddHour(-1) calculates correctly the date if last shift 
/// was "yesterday"
private Shift lastShift(List<Shift> shifts, DateTime startTime)
{
    if (shifts.Count > 0)
    {
        var now = startTime;
        var time = new TimeSpan(now.Hour, now.Minute, now.Second);
        var shiftRunning = (from s in shifts
                            let frame = (time - s.BeginTime).Hours
                            where frame > 0 && frame < s.LengthHours
                            select s).FirstOrDefault();
        if (shiftRunning == null)
        {
            shiftRunning = lastShift(shifts, startTime.AddHours(-1));
        }
        return shiftRunning;
    }
    return null;
}

private Shift findShift(List<Shift> shifts)
{
    return lastShift(shifts, DateTime.Now);
}
```

It could be used like this:

```
var shifts = new List<Shift>
{
    new Shift { Name = "C", BeginTime = new TimeSpan(22, 00, 00), LengthHours = 8 },
    new Shift { Name = "A", BeginTime = new TimeSpan(06, 00, 00), LengthHours = 8 },
    new Shift { Name = "B", BeginTime = new TimeSpan(14, 00, 00), LengthHours = 6 },
    new Shift { Name = "D", BeginTime = new TimeSpan(11, 00, 00), LengthHours = 8 }
};

var shiftRunning = findShift(shifts);
```

The order of the shifts is not important any more, the most recent one will be always picked (because of the correct calculation using AddHour(-1)). Because of the recursion there is no need for double checks and complex if conditions. Overlaping shifts and gaps are also covered because of the recursion.

Comment: This will return *one* (an arbitrary one) of the shifts that started within the last 8 hours. But it will not return the most recent shift if for some reason there was not a shift that started within the last 8 hours. It also will not necessarily return the *last* shift that started with in the last 8 hours if there were multiple shifts that started within the last 8 hours (i.e. if they overlap, which in the OP's case they can).

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic find-the-maximum problem.  You should only update `mostRecentShift` if it is `null` or if the shift being examined started more recently.  At the moment you're updating it regardless.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a C# guru and I don't quite understand the type of TimeSpan.
the following **pseudo** code might work if you simply think BeginTime is a integer value range from 0~23:

```
Shift mostRecentShift = null;
foreach (Shift aShift in shifts) 
{
    Shift goodShift = null;
    if(aShift.BeginTime <= currentTime)
        if(aShift.BeginTime + aShift.LengthHours > currentTime)
            goodShift = aShift;
    else if(24 - aShift.BeginTime < aShift.LengthHours - currentTime)
        goodShift = aShift;

    if(goodShift != null)
    {
        if(mostRecentShift == null)
            mostRecentShift = goodShift;
        else if(mostRecentShift.BeginTime < goodShift.BeginTime)
            mostRecentShift = goodShift;
    }
}
```

Given a List of 8 hour Shifts (which BeginTime's are 6am, 2pm, 10pm respectively), 
This code cared about the 0:00 ~ 5:59am